# Plutus Pioneers Program Environment Setting, nix-shell command cause syntax error, 8.10.5 is out of date

Tags: nix-shell

I'm encountered syntax error message as below when I command "nix-shell" to build environment setting. Could you advise what makes this error message?

--- error message ---

trace: WARNING: 8.10.5 is out of date, consider using 8.10.7.
error: syntax error, unexpected end of file at /nix/store/14hkipxfa9j8ngs02f7llgpqr4l7mrdq-happy-plan-to-nix-pkgs/default.nix:1:1:

--- end of error message ---

My system setting :
OS : ubuntu 20.04lts

I've completed following steps in advance to set up environment.

sudo sh -c 'apt update && apt install curl' to install curl

sudo apt-get install vim to install vim

sudo apt-get install git to install git

sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon to install nix via single user

sudo vim nix.conf  to create a new nix.conf file

Paste the following lines:

substituters = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
experimental-features = nix-command

git clone https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps to clone the correct plutus-apps repo

git checkout 7f53f18dfc788bf6aa929f47d840efa1247e11fd

nix-build -A plutus-playground.server

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like we're following the same instructions to install the IOHK binary caches with a couple of small differences, and honestly, I have no idea whether this makes any difference. I believe that may have used the multi-user installation for nix. After cloning the `plutus-apps` repository, I ran `cabal update`, and then `nix-shell`. Once that was finished, I just followed the README and ran `cabal build plutus-pab`. I then followed the instructions on page 2 of this document -> https://docs.google.com/document/d/13112LHG9vVvNUs40oZSqZ-DF6_yFiT_SJZ2NaEmjMM4/edit# although I did not do step 3 (`nix-build -A plutus-playground.server`), and it seems to work fine. I hope you manage to find the issue

Comment: Actually the error message "out of date" were not root cause of syntax error. I checked out both plutus-pioneer-program and plutus-apps and then ran again above command and pass through this error. Thanks your comments it was helpful. You made me think differently.